# List databound to a datagridview and feedback on a progress bar

Tags: c#, .net

I'm populating a datagridview with

```
MyDataGridView.DataSource = MyList;
```

where MyList is a List < MyClass > .
Now i want a progressbar to be filled while datagridview is populating. 
I can do MyProgessBar.Maximum = MyList.Count, but how can I set MyProgressBar value every time a row is drawn?

Comment: http://www.vbdotnetforums.com/windows-forms/25999-load-datagridview-via-backgroundworker-progressbar-feedback.html

Comment: is backgroundworker the only way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's solution with backgroundworker...I didnt find anything else but this works for what I have to do

```
    private void PopulateDataGridView()
    {
        MyProgressBar.Value = 0;
        MyProgressBar.Maximum = MyList.Count;
        MyBackGroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        MyDataGridView.DataSource = MyList;
    }
```

and then

```
    private void MyBackGroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            MyBackGroundWorker.ReportProgress(MyDataGridView.Rows.Count);
            if (MyDataGridView.Rows.Count == MyProgressBar.Maximum)
            {
                break;
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        }

    }

    private void MyBackGroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyProgressBar.Value = MyDataGridView.Rows.Count;
    }
```